# Python Data Optimal Spreading of Parameters

Tags: python, statistics

Let's assume that I have a certain number of parameters that describe a system:

i.e.

```
position, velocity, mass, length, width
```

Now every parameter has an associated upper and lower bound:

```
position = [0,100]
velocity = [10,300]
mass = [50,200]
length = [2,10]
width = [2,10]
```

A data-point is defined by a certain combination of these parameters:
i.e.

```
data_point = [10,250,50,4,2]
```

Now, the question is: **Is there a python package/algorithm such that I can initialize a certain number of data-points (i.e. 5) such that those data points are optimally spread over the parameter space.**

Side Note:

Yes, I know "optimally spread" is not well defined, but I am really not sure about how to go here. One possible definition could be:

maximize the distance between the data-points (Euclidean distance between vectors)

**EDIT:**

Using linspace is a very good idea. However, I quickly noticed an issues with my data. I actually forgot to talk about constraints:

Some data-points are not possible. i.e.

```
constraints = [lenght*2-width, position-velocity]
```

...if these values are greater or equal to zero, then the data-point can be considered as feasible.

So my question is: ***How can I include constraints in a smart way?***

Using linspace, you will see that velocity will always be greater than position, and thus we will get no feasible datapoint.

```
position = [0,100]
velocity = [10,300]
mass = [50,200]
length = [2,10]
width = [2,10]

# Find Samples 
start = [s[0] for s in [position, velocity, mass, length, width]]
end = [s[1] for s in [position, velocity, mass, length, width]]

num_samples = 5
samples = np.linspace(start, end, num_samples)

print(samples)
```

This is the output:

```
[[  0.   10.   50.    2.    2. ]
 [ 25.   82.5  87.5   4.    4. ]
 [ 50.  155.  125.    6.    6. ]
 [ 75.  227.5 162.5   8.    8. ]
 [100.  300.  200.   10.   10. ]]
```

Now, let's check the constraints:

```
def check_constraint(samples, constraints):
    
    
    checked_samples = []
    for dimensions in samples:
        position, velocity, mass, length, width = dimensions

        # Here I am checking the constraints:
        if any([i<0 for i in [length*2-width, position-velocity]]):
            pass
        else:
            checked_samples.append(dimensions)
            
    
    return checked_samples

samples_checked = check_onstraint(samples, constraints)
print(samples_checked)
```

These would be the samples left after checking the constraints:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to get an even grid of points:

```
import numpy as np

...

start = [s[0] for s in [position, velocity, ...]]
end = [s[1] for s in [position, velocity, ...]]

num_samples = 5
samples = np.linspace(start, end, num_samples)
```

This will return points evenly spaced throughout the parameter space.

**Edit**
To include more constraints it might be good to do something like:

```
start = ...
end = ...
num_results = 5
results = []

while len(results) < num_results:
    sample = np.random.uniform(start, end)
    if is_valid(sample):
        results.append(sample)
```

that way you can define the `is_valid` function and check any conditions you'd like! The resulting points should be uniformly distributed around the parameter space.

Comment: Interesting. How would you deal with the lower and upper bounds? More specifically, how do you define start, and end?

Comment: The bounds are extracted from the first and last elements of the input parameter bounds in the inline for loop for `start` and `end`

Comment: So for example: [s[0] for s in [[0,100], [0,300], [50,200], [2,10], [2,10]] ] ?

Comment: That's actually very smart! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question. Would be curious if you see a way to solve this?

Comment: updated the answer! Hopefully that'll help out

Comment: Really nice! Thank you so much ! Last question: Would you also know how to make sure that the output is only integers? Do you know if you can ask "uniform" to only output integer values? Thanks a lot!

Quick thing:  In your code, I think "r" needs to be "result".

Comment: Thought about using "randint" but I am not sure if it is uniformly distributed...

Comment: Yep, you're right I fixed the `r`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html makes it sound like randint should be uniform!